# Rust multiple borrowing struct

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership

I am new to Rust and trying to implement a simple TCP-Server that sends me a live image. Therefore I am using this crate https://crates.io/crates/tinybmp for the `RawBmp`-type. Now I am struggling a bit to understand some of Rusts functionality. Or let's say I am still trying to figure out how to accomplish this in the 'Rust way'.

```rust
pub struct TCPBasePackage {
    haspayload: bool,
    pkgbytes: Vec<u8>,
}

impl TCPBasePackage {
    pub const CMD: i32 = 0;

    pub fn new() -> TCPBasePackage {
        TCPBasePackage { haspayload: false, pkgbytes: Vec::new()}
    }
}

impl TCPPackage for TCPBasePackage {
    fn serialize(&mut self) -> &[u8] {
        self.pkgbytes.append(&mut self.get_command().to_be_bytes().to_vec());        
        self.pkgbytes.append(&mut [u8::from(self.haspayload)].to_vec());
        self.pkgbytes.as_slice()
    }

    fn read_from_stream(&mut self, mut stream: &TcpStream) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut vec: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        let mut buf_pkg: [u8; 5] = [0; 5];
        stream.read_exact(&mut buf_pkg).unwrap();
        vec.append(&mut buf_pkg.to_vec());
        self.pkgbytes = vec.to_vec();
        return self.pkgbytes.clone();
    }

    fn deserialize(&mut self, buff: &[u8]) -> i32 {
        self.haspayload = buff[4] != 0;
        return 5;
    }

    fn get_command(&self) -> i32 {
        TCPBasePackage::CMD
    }
}

pub struct MsgLiveImage<'a> {
    tcppackage: TCPBasePackage,
    imgbytes: Vec::<u8>,
    img: RawBmp<'a>,
}

impl<'a> MsgLiveImage<'a> {
    pub const CMD: i32 = 2;

    pub fn new() -> MsgLiveImage<'static> {
        MsgLiveImage { 
tcppackage: TCPBasePackage { haspayload: false, pkgbytes: Vec::new() },
            imgbytes: Vec::new(),
            img: RawBmp::from_slice(&[]).unwrap()
        }
    }

    pub fn set_image_data(&'a mut self, data: Vec::<u8>) {
        self.imgbytes = data;
        self.img = RawBmp::from_slice(&self.imgbytes.as_slice()).unwrap();
    }

}
```

In some function of my application I want to do this:

```rust
fn write_response_to_stream(
    mut request: &Box<dyn mytcp::TCPPackage>,
    mut stream: &TcpStream,
    raspicam: &Arc<Mutex<camserv::CamServ>>,
) -> Result<Box<dyn mytcp::TCPPackage>, &'static str> {
    match request.get_command() {
        mytcp::MsgLiveImage::CMD => {
            let mut pkg = mytcp::MsgLiveImage::new();
            {
                {
                    let tmpcam = raspicam.lock().unwrap(); // lock the camera server 
                    let tmpbuff = tmpcam.imgbuff.lock().unwrap(); // lock the buffer of last image
                    pkg.set_image_data((*tmpbuff).clone()); // make copy of my image and transfer ownership of that copy to the package struct
                }
                {
                    let sbuff = pkg.serialize();
                    stream.write(&sbuff);
                }
                stream.flush();
            }
            Ok(Box::new(pkg)) // return the response package
        }
        _ => Err("Unknown request package"),
    }
}
```

But the problem is, that the compiler is complaining about multiple borrowing the `pkg`-variable. As well as moving the `pkg` out of scope (which i learned should be possible by wrapping it in a `Box`.
Can someone explain me why the first mutable borrow still lasts even after the method returns? How can i achieve to call multiple methods on my struct without getting these borrowing conflicts?

Errors from rustc:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `pkg` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/raspiserv/mod.rs:90:33
   |
87 |                     pkg.set_image_data((*tmpbuff).clone());
   |                     -------------------------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
90 |                     let sbuff = pkg.serialize();
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
95 |             Ok(Box::new(pkg))
   |             ----------------- returning this value requires that `pkg` is borrowed for `'static`

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `pkg`
  --> src/raspiserv/mod.rs:95:13
   |
87 |                     pkg.set_image_data((*tmpbuff).clone());
   |                     -------------------------------------- `pkg` is borrowed here
...
95 |             Ok(Box::new(pkg))
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `pkg` because it is borrowed
  --> src/raspiserv/mod.rs:95:25
   |
87 |                     pkg.set_image_data((*tmpbuff).clone());
   |                     -------------------------------------- borrow of `pkg` occurs here
...
95 |             Ok(Box::new(pkg))
   |             ------------^^^--
   |             |           |
   |             |           move out of `pkg` occurs here
   |             returning this value requires that `pkg` is borrowed for `'static`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `set_image_data`

```rust
    pub fn set_image_data(&'a mut self, data: Vec::<u8>) {
        self.imgbytes = data;
        self.img = RawBmp::from_slice(&self.imgbytes.as_slice()).unwrap();
    }
```

you borrow self for the lifetime of `'a` which is as long as the `RawBmp` inside of it is valid.
Thus the borrow lasts as long as the struct.

What you have is a self referential struct see [this question on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct/32300133#32300133) for suggestions how to reslove this.

You can probably just drop the `img` from `MsgLiveImage` and replace it with a method:

```rust
impl MsgLiveImage {
    pub fn as_img<'a>(&'a self) -> Result<RawBmp<'a>, ParseError> {
        RawBmp::from_slice(&self.imgbytes.as_slice())
    }
}
```

Might even be able to omit the lifetimes from that.